# Scheme: How to merge two streams

Tags: scheme

I have got these functions

```
(define force!
  (lambda (thunk)
    (thunk)))


(define stream-head
  (lambda (s n)
    (if (zero? n)
        '()
        (cons (car s)
              (stream-head (force! (cdr s))
                           (1- n))))))

(define make-stream
  (lambda (seed next)
    (letrec ([produce (lambda (current)
                        (cons current
                              (lambda ()
                                (produce (next current)))))])
      (produce seed))))



(define make-traced-stream
  (lambda (seed next)
    (letrec ([produce (trace-lambda produce (current)
                        (cons current
                              (lambda ()
                                (produce (next current)))))])
      (produce seed))))

(define stream-of-even-natural-numbers
  (make-traced-stream 0
                      (lambda (n)
                        (+ n 2))))

(define stream-of-odd-natural-numbers
  (make-traced-stream 1
                      (lambda (n)
                        (+ n 2))))
```

And I need to make a function that merges the last two, so that if I run

```
(stream-head (merge-streams stream-of-even-natural-numbers stream-of-odd-natural-numbers) 10)
```

I must get the output (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9).. how is this done?

The best idea I had, which is wrong, have been:

```
(define merge-streams
  (lambda (x y)
    (cons (car x)
          (merge-streams y (cdr x)))))
```

Comment: @chris Sorry about the edit (I didn't notice there were one).

Comment: @soegaard Oh, it's okay, it's just that I hand-indented (including the correct semantic meaning of `trace-lambda`), so I prefer to keep that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion:

```
(define (merge-streams s1 s2)
  (cond
    [(empty-stream? s1) s2)] ; nothing to merge from s1
    [(empty-stream? s2) s1)] ; nothing to merge from s2
    [else (let ([h1 (stream-car s1)]
                [h2 (stream-car s2)])
            (cons h1 
              (lambda ()
                (cons h2 
                  (stream-merge (stream-rest s1) 
                                (stream-rest s2))))))]))
```

It uses some helper functions that must be defined first.

Comment: Since OP intends to call `stream-head` on the result it seems for me that this should produce a stream instead of a list.

Comment: I added a (lambda () ...) in order to turn the merged streams into a stream (I hope I got the representation right).

Comment: I managed to understand what you were doing and I came up with my own solution after that. 
`(define (merge-streams s1 s2)
   (cons
     (car s1)
     (delay (merge-streams s2 (force!(cdr s1))))))`